# Java Type Mapping for Java Native Access

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a C function defined as follows:

```
int s3vold_(void) {...}
```

To create a Java methods with the same argument type as the native function does the void parameter map to Pointer or nothing? E.g.,

```
int s3vold(Pointer p) {...}
```

or

```
int s3vold() {...}
```

The [JNA docs](https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#marshalling) only refer to void*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `void` parameter maps to nothing. The `void` parameter in C is equivalent to an empty parameter list: in other languages we leave this blank, but in C we write `void` to distinguish from a classic K&R function declaration.